# MySQL return rows with multiple values in one column?

Tags: mysql

this is my scenario: I have a table that holds recipes, and another that holds ingredients  linked to a recipe (recipe_ingredients).

TABLE RECIPE_INGREDIENTS:

```
ID      RECIPE_ID     INGREDIENT_ID
1           1              6
2           2              3
3           2              4
```

in my case, I want to return all recipes with some ingredients introduced by user (could be one or more), in this example let's say all recipes with ingredients 3 and 4. Obviusly when I only query for one ingredient there's no problem, but I don't know how achieve that with more than one... 
Thanks all in advance! any advice is welcome!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you want this:

```
select RECIPE_ID
from RECIPE_INGREDIENTS
where INGREDIENT_ID in (3, 4)
group by RECIPE_ID
having count(distinct INGREDIENT_ID ) >=2
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b6672/1)

Then if you want to join this to you recipe table:

```
select r.*
from recipes r
inner join
(
  select RECIPE_ID
  from RECIPE_INGREDIENTS
  where INGREDIENT_ID in (3, 4)
  group by RECIPE_ID
  having count(distinct INGREDIENT_ID ) >=2
) ri
  on r.RECIPE_ID = ri.RECIPE_ID
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you have 3 tables recipes , ingradients and recipe_ingrediants

```
SELECT 
    r.*,
    GROUP_CONCAT(i.ingradients)
FROM recipes as r
LEFT JOIN recipe_ingrediants as ri ON ri.recipe_id = r.id
LEFT JOIN ingrediants as i ON r.id = ri.ingrediant_id
GROUP BY r.id
```